# Android: EditTextPreference converts String to numeric

Tags: android, android-edittext, preferenceactivity

I have a simple PreferenceActivity with an EditTextPreference.
My problem is that I set the default text to be a phone number (such as +14047771000)
but when the preference is clicked it is shown as a double (in the above example - 1.404771E10).  What can I do to prevent this and display the text as String?
thanks, Joel

edit: Here is the xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:title="IMS Preferences">
 <PreferenceCategory android:title="Sip User">
  <EditTextPreference android:key="PublicId"
   android:title="Public ID" android:defaultValue="+14047771000"/>
 </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

EDIT:
anyone? any idea?

Comment: What do you mean it is shown as a double? Show us your xml

Comment: Hint: you should be able to edit your original question to incorporate the xml snippet with formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You can / need to set the text type in the xml declaration. E.g.

`<EditText android:inputType="phone" ....`